# compile error C2099: initializer is not a constant

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

The following code wont compile:

```
const int a = 0;

struct Test
{
    int b;
};

static const struct Test test = 
{
    a
};
```

Its a cut down example of what I am really trying to do, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to compile this in separate project? Looks perfect to me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C89/90 version of C language all aggregate initializers must consist of *constants* only. In C language terminology a *constant* of `int` type is a literal value, like `10`, `20u`, `0x1` etc. Enum members are also constants. Variables of `const int` type are *not* constants in C. You can't use a `const int` variable in aggregate initializer. (For this reason, in C language, when you need to declare a named constant you should use either `#define` or `enum`, but not `const` qualifier.)

In C99 this requirement for aggregate initializers was relaxed. It is now OK to use non-constants in aggregate initializers of local objects. However, for static objects (as in your example) the requirement still holds. So, even in C99 you'l' have to either use

```
#define a 0
```

or use a named enum constant as suggested in @R..'s answer.

Comment: +1, more complete than my answer, even if slightly off on a few points. You might want to use the phrase "constant expression" though rather than "constants", since the former has an official definition in the C language, and makes it clear that complex expressions can satisfy the requirement as long as their constituent components are "sufficiently constant".

Answer (score 7):

`a` is not a constant expression. It's a `const`-qualified variable. If you want a symbolic name that you can use in constant expressions, you need either a preprocessor macro (`#define a 0`) or an enum (`enum { a = 0 };`).

Comment: As a note - this is different in C++, which will let you use `const` qualified integer variables initialized with constant expressions in other constant expressions.

Comment: Noted. Is it also different in Java and C#? How about Python? Or lisp? ;-)