# error c2099 initlizer is not a const how can i get rid of this error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have following in my header file

```
typedef unsigned int FRAMEBIT;

   typedef struct Msg_Node
   {
FRAMEBIT Msg_Id;
FRAMEBIT MSg_Indx;
FRAMEBIT Msg_Size;
struct cmd_Header* pcmd_attr;
struct Msg_Node *pNext;
   }Msg_Node_T;
```

and in source file

```
      static Msg_Node_T MSG[ 6 ] = {
        {  0 , 112 , &MSG[1]} ,
        {  113 , 32 , &MSG[2]} ,
        {  146 , 64 ,  &MSG[3]} ,
        {  211 , 72 ,  &MSG[4]} ,
        {  284 , 64 ,  &MSG[5]} ,
        {  349 , 32 , 0} 
      };
```

and getting an `error c2099 initliazer is not a constant` how can i remove this error?
why  this error is coming?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743276/error-c2099-initializer-is-not-a-constant

Comment: @HeenaGoyal that example is not helping me ?
in that example u have suggested it has I2c_send initialized but am giving the values directly here ?
am little bit confused can u make it clear for me ?

Comment: see the code which i have edited i.e. `struct node *pNext;` and some semi colon because same code i have tried is working at my side.

Comment: No repro with Visual Studio 2010 and above.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis i didnt get u james

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles and runs for me without issue in g++ 4.8.1. Did you forget the semicolon after the node_T typedef? I added that and I capitalized node (Edit: you seem to have fixed that in your example). (I also changed a little bit in the MSG initialization but nothing important.) Other than that, the code is the same.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned int FRAMEBIT;

typedef struct Node
 {
  FRAMEBIT node_size;
  FRAMEBIT node_index;
  struct Node *pNext;
 }node_T;


 static node_T  MSG[ 4 ] = {
         {  0 , 112 , &MSG[1]} ,
         {  113 , 32 , &MSG[2]} ,
         {  146 , 64 , &MSG[3]} ,
         {  211 , 72 , &MSG[0]}
     };


 int main(){

    //prints 112 as expected
    std::cout << MSG[0].node_index;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: no i have it in my code but forgot it while posting it here but still the code isnt working properly ? am working with visual studio

Comment: @user3388427:: If you have that in your code, then post the exact code that can reproduce the error. Kindly edit the code in your question.

Comment: i have run it in visual studio 2010. it is not giving any error

Comment: i have made some changes in the code that i have posted that is the exact code what am i dealing with

Comment: Well, now you need another value in your initializer to account for all 4 struct members